# Openlayers 4.6.4, Can't get BingMap attributions using source.getAttributions()

Tags: openlayers

We use BingMap in our application and call the source.getAttributions() to print the bing attributions on the pdf.
After upgrading to OL4.6.4, source.getattributions() return null. 
Post https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/7329 explains why getattributions() for bing map is returning null.

Is there any workaround to get the Bing attriibutions in the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work again in v5.0, but what you get from `getAttributions()` will be a function which you call with the `FrameState`. Something like

```
var getAttribution = bingSource().getAttributions();
var attribution = getAttribution({
  extent: map.getView().calculateExtent(),
  viewState: map.getView().getState()
});
```

Or even easier in a listener for the map's 'postcompose' or 'postrender' event:

```
var getAttribution = bingSource().getAttributions();
map.on('postcompose', function(e) {
  var attribution = getAttribution(e.frameState);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response but is there workaround until v5.0 is available ? and any idea when v5.0 will be released?

Comment: You can already install ol v5.0.0-beta.3 from npm if you want to upgrade. The final v5.0.0 release will be out in March.

Comment: Ok , will do. Thanks